# Autocomplete using JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

In my view i have

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(per => per.Hospital, new { 
    style = "width:220px", @maxlength = "50", 
    data_autocomplete = Url.Action("HospitalList", "Person") })
```

My jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('input[data-autocomplete]').each(function () {
        var url = $(this).data('autocomplete');
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.getJSON(url, {
                    term: request.term
                }, response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And I created a new Action result

```
public ActionResult HospitalList(string term)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    result.Add("Hospital 1");
    result.Add("NYUMC");
    result.Add("Christ");
    result.Add("Bellevue");
    result.Add("NewYork-Presbyterian");
    result.Add("North Central Bronx Hospital");   

    result = result.Where(r => r.Contains(term)).ToList();         

    return Json(result , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I included a jquery library

```
<script src='<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQueryUI/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>'    type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src='<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQueryUI/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js") %>'  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

now where am i going wrong. All I see a a text box , no behavior of auto complete.

Comment: Any JS console errors?  Are jquery and jquery-ui loading (the path on the jquery file `"~/Scripts/jQueryUI/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"` catches my eye, but that doesn't mean it is wrong. ;)

Comment: No error. for eg if i enter "h". nothing happens. I added a break point in my ActionResult HospitalList(string term) method. the query is executed and the jason returns 2 results but that all I see in my ui is h in my textbox no suggestions of the 2 results

Comment: where is the css for ui? I think you are missing the stylesheet for jquery-ui

Comment: I have no css for ui. I guess u r right what css should i be putting

Comment: Added CSS working thanks Muhammad. u the best. I was on it since morning...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery UI Team did not add support for jQuery 1.4.3 even until version 1.8.6 of UI (see [here](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/11/jquery-ui-1-8-6/)). Therefore, although you may have other issues going on, you also have a potential library incompatibility.

Upgrade your versions of both libraries and see where that takes you first.

http://jquery.com/download/
http://jqueryui.com/download/
Or
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

I hope this helps.